# wide angle and macro lens converter or adapter

Tags: lens, macro, fisheye

I'm new to the world of photography and also have a pretty tight budget, so I'm interested if anyone has tried using a wide angle + macro lens converter/adaptor such as [this](http://photojojo.com/store/awesomeness/wide-angle-macro-lens/) (Forum discussion about that is [here](http://www.fotomedia.com.my/forum/showthread.php?t=9273))?

From what I can see it is something that is attached in front of our standard zoom / kit lens, and then we can view wide or macro without having to obtain specifically expensive macro lens or wide lens. See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUmay6zQKRo) & [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGNDoS7Y_S4).

My concern is, what is the effect towards our lens motor or something. I means could it damage our lens?

Other concern is, how was the quality?

Glad if someone could share their experience.

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the effect on motor - as it screws onto the filter thread there is virtually no danger to the lens motor under normal operation. If you use a lens with a non-rotating front element (and filter thread), then only excessive force when mounting it may damage the thread.

If using a lens with a rotating front element (like the Canon 18-55mm kit lens), then you should set the focus switch to Manual (MF) before screwing the attachment, as you should do with any screw-on filter. Otherwise - some people claim that it can damage your autofocus motor.

As for the image quality - I never used one of these so I can't comment directly, but in photography optics, you get what you pay for. For $50 a piece for two lenses (wide, macro) I would not expect a stellar quality, but OTOH, there are cheaper kits around.

Comment: thanks for sharing your view, i've got kit lens where I want to try this to, I'll keep in mind about the rotating front element, it's make a sense because the converter/adapter surely quite heavy for AF motor should not design for that.

Comment: @Nazmin - I actually think that the weight of that converter will NOT be a problem for your lens. What I was saying is that when you put it on or take it off your lens, switch the lens from auto to manual focus mode. This way the AF motor is disengaged and the moment you apply will not hurt it. Note that if your lens has a Full-Time-Manual AF mode, then this is not a problem - but I don't think there are USM FTM lenses with a rotating element anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I got an Opteka Fish eye filter which is pretty much the same as this, it was fun to use but the images weren't very crisp.

Also I had it attached to my 50mm 1.8 prime and forgot to take it off before putting it in my bag, the extra torque from the length of the filter ripped the front end of the lens out of the lens, now it just falls out periodically and has issues auto-focusing. I know this was a rookie mistake but I was a rookie and I made that mistake.

if you can't afford the real lenses these will do for playing around, you might even get some good pictures, but the real deal costs a lot for a reason, if you want to go pro invest in some proper glass.

Comment: Of course Omar, I'm also a rookie, and we do a lot silly mistakes, but thanks for sharing the experience.